# Android how to use picasso with GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask, custom-adapter

I am trying to use the Picasso library in order to load movie posters from the TMDB API into a grid view using an AsyncTask so I used a custom adapter, but nothing happens, so I tried loading a single hardcoded image, but it didn't load also. I put a breakpoint in the "getView" method of my custom adapter and noticed it never fires...
So, what am I doing wrong here?

This is my custom adapter:

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MovieEntity> {
    private Context context;
    private List<MovieEntity> movies = new ArrayList<>();

    public MoviesAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<MovieEntity> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movies.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MovieEntity getItem(int position) {
        return movies.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = new ImageView(context);
            view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        }

        MovieEntity movieEntity = getItem(position);

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(movieEntity.moviePoster)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .fit()
                .tag(context)
                .into(view);

        return view;
    }
}
```

and this is my code in the "onCreateView" method:

```
mMoviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.grid_view_image_item,
                R.id.img_movie_poster,
                new ArrayList<MovieEntity>());

        GridView gridView = (GridView) rootVoew.findViewById(R.id.grid_movies);
        gridView.setAdapter(mMoviesAdapter);
```

The data is being set in the AsyncTask onPostExecute method like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
            if (strings != null) {
                mMoviesAdapter.clear();
                mMoviesAdapter.addAll(strings);
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here that there are no images in my grid view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most optimal solution, but it works in my case.
I just removed the

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movies.size();
}
```

from the custom adapter and it probably had its own `getCount`...

Answer (score 0):

I assume `mForecastList` is array list and your `mMoviesAdapter` as adapter for your `mForecastList`.

In your onCreateView

```
  mForecastList = new ArrayList<MovieEntity>();
  mMoviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.grid_view_image_item,
            R.id.img_movie_poster, mForecastList);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) rootVoew.findViewById(R.id.grid_movies);
    gridView.setAdapter(mMoviesAdapter);
```

In your postExecute mmethod. do this..

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
        if (strings != null) {
            if(mForecastList != null) {
              mForecastList.clear();
            }
            // If `strings` is json data parse it to ArrayList<MovieEntity>
        //    mForecastList.addAll(stringsList);
            // Call notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the data in the grid..
            mMoviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally copied from another project, it's the same code but another name. I fixed it to be the correct name of 'mMoviesAdapter'. According to the documentation, the method 'addAll' calls the 'notifyDataSetChanged' by default unless you specify the 'mNotifyOnChange' to be false.

Comment: No, I just copied it wrong here in my question... I guess it is because the `getCount` method returns 0, but why ???

Comment: I hope it is a json string from onPostExcute() param. So you have to pass that json to ArrayList<MovieEntity>

Comment: It is not getCount method, its about data you are parsing.. If you can't parse the data then it will not be stored in arraylist....

Comment: I have a method that parse the string into a json array, the data is valid and there is no problem with it. I believe  the problem is in the `getCount` method, but I don't know thy it returns 0...